# How can I display the number of items per category in the Django admin filter panel?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-admin-filters

In Django admin, how could I add the number of items for each category of a filter directly in the filter panel (see mock-up below)?

**Current filter panel**

[image: Current filter]

**Desired filter panel**

[image: Desired filter]

**Model**

I am filtering my `UserProfile` table by its `languages` field. This is a many-to-many field on the `Language` table.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ...
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank=True)

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # ...
```

My current admin configuration is:

```
@admin.register(UserProfile):
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_filter = ('languages',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class UserProfileLanguageFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Language')
    parameter_name = 'languages'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        # Return a list of (id, name) for lookups. We return the language_id and the string format "Language Name (Count of Users)" as the name.
        return [(i, "{}({})".format(j, k)) for i, j, k in
                qs.values_list('languages__id', 'languages__name').annotate(
                    user_count=Count('userprofile')).distinct().order_by(
                    'languages__name')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():  # Use the lookup id we sent above; to filter
            return queryset.filter(languages__id=self.value())


@admin.register(UserProfile):
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_filter = (UserProfileLanguageFilter,)
```

I'd definitely encourage you to understand the Filter and also the Queryset better, if you choose to pick up code directly.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! It also works with related fields.
NB: I had to use `Count('user')` as I needed to count a field from the `UserProfile` model.

Answer (score 1):

Django 5.0 will feature facet counts via the `admin.ModelAdmin`.

You just pick one of the following options in your admin class.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    show_facets = admin.ShowFacets.ALLOW  # default - when '_facets' in URL query string
    show_facets = admin.ShowFacets.ALWAYS # show always
    show_facets = admin.ShowFacets.NEVER  # always disabled
    ...
```

Please cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.show_facets

Comment: Interesting add in Django 5 but unfortunately it just chokes on my custom filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter by extending the `admin.SimpleListFilter` as explained in [list_filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

> a class inheriting from django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter, which
>   you need to provide the title and parameter_name attributes to and
>   override the lookups and queryset methods